# How to check database connectivity in Zend Framework 1.12.11

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am new to Zend Framework and I have installed it on my local server.
Below is my application.ini:

```
[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.dbname = "zendy"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = ""
```

I have created a database named `zendy` and created a table named `country` with two rows.
I have created country.php in my models folder and below is my code for it:

```
class Application_Model_country extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'country';
     protected $_primary = 'id';
}
```

Below mentioned code is my indexController.php:

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $c = new Application_Model_country();
        $this->view->country=$c->fetchAll();
    }


}
```

But it throw an error in browser.

**An error occurred**

**Application error**

I have tried to debug from ErrorController.php it display error like:

```
protected 'message' => string 'Primary key column(s) (id) are not columns in this table ()' (length=59)
```

But while I have created the country-table in my database I've already applied a primary key.

Can anyone please help me out why this error happens? Is my ZF-project connected to the database?
Or do i miss anything?

Comment: make sure your country table has primary key `id` and it is set to auto increment. Can you share your  table structure ?

Comment: yes i already applied primary key and auto increment in my table in DB

Comment: The error suggests that your application can connect to the database. Check for trailing spaces in the column names.

Comment: I have check trailing spaces in my DB ..it is ok..can you help me to overcome an error?

Comment: Try this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955062/primary-key-columns-id-are-not-columns-in-this-table

Comment: Maybe you can try do drop `protected $_primary = 'id';` and let Zend read this information by itself?

Comment: @Volvox i have earlier tried without     protected $_primary = 'id';  but it wont effected so i try to add it in code.

Comment: Maybe it is a typing error. Try [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28875252/3351765) with `var_dump('"' . $col_name . '" - ' . ($col_desc['PRIMARY'] ? 'true' : 'false'));` instead of `var_dump($ col_name);`. It will tell you which is the field that Zend considers to be primary